# How to design outlined textfield in iOS without pods

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm looking for ideas on how to design textfield like below (UIKit) natively without using any pods

Im looking for outlined text like "Label Text"

Any ideas pls?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `UITextField` and an image view, placed inside a UIView that has a `layer.borderWidth`, `layer.borderColor`, and `layer.cornerRadius` set on it, and then a UILabel placed on top of the container view so that it partly covers the view's rounded rectangle border.

I'd suggest composing a custom `UIView` structured like that.

Answer (score 0):

Im able to create this just using storyboard by adding view and textfield inside view and a overlapping label onto view

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a textField and place a UIView on Upper left boarder.
2. Take a label and place that label centre vertically and horizontally upon that UIView. You will get this.